# Strange issue in Wi-Fi in laptop , Weak signal

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, hardware-failure, wifi-driver

I had been facing issues with Wi-Fi signal in my laptop (2 day from now) and thought it to be some issue of drivers. I installed the latest drivers but it came out to be of no use. then i thought it to be a WIFI card issue and ignored it since i am afraid of opening my laptop. but now i noticed that whenever I tilt my laptop screen beyond 100 degree(or beyond perpendicular) the Wi-Fi signals drop extremely. So is it still some software issue or hardware .. like the Wi-Fi wires are loose or are broken.
Please help
thanks
My laptop specs - DELL E7440
i7 4600u
4gb ddr3
DELL 1506 Wi-Fi card

Comment: There is not enough in the question to answer it.

Comment: I can imagine your laptop going into aeroplane mode (no wifi at all) when you close the lid, but not that anything would change depending on how far you tilt the screen.  But a bad connection yes, or reception being influenced by the position of the antenna in the screen.  Tilt it to obtain the best reception, then turn your laptop to see if you can get a better one.  Or put it somewhere else.

Comment: "I tilt my laptop screen beyond 100 degree(or beyond ) ...  I am afraid of opening my laptop."    <-- Take it to a local repair shop and have it checked inside.

Comment: tilting the laptop will change the angle of the receiver but it could be a HW damage too...also it could be that you have some new device nearby causing interference... as David said - not enough information and as John said a local repair shop should be able to detect what your issue is.

Comment: Laptops normally have the WiFi card's antennas run up either side of the screen and this is likely why you're experiencing signal drop when opening beyond 100 degrees. To fix, **(1)** adjust the WiFi card's properties _(`WinKey`+`R` → `ncpa.cpl` → OK → Right-click WiFi adapter → Properties → Configure → Advanced)_, ensuring _WMM_ is enabled, _Channel Width_ is not set to 20MHz, and _Transmit Power_ is set to 5/highest; **(2)** Adjust your router's WiFi antennas if they're external and adjust the transmit power _(if available)_ in the router's WebUI

Comment: i know that wifi antenna wire are going to the laptop screen so what i thought is that maybe the wires are getting stretched and it could be that the antenna wires connected to wifi card are loose. But i still need some confirmation and open my laptops back panel.

Comment: @JW0914 there is no WMM and channel width settings or transmit power option

Comment: @JW0914 all i see is this https://imgur.com/a/wQtCTO8

Comment: @mr.anonymous The antenna wires are not getting stretched and you don't need to open your laptop until you've ruled out all others, as the antennas can not come loose from the wifi card due to how the connector works, as it mechanically locks itself to the card. The other thing I forgot to mention is you'll want to verify your router's WiFi radios are set to actual channels and not _Auto_: **2.4GHz:** `1`, `6`, or `11` | **5Ghz:** `157` if in the US, else the highest channel available.

Comment: it was working fine few days ago and suddenly this issue popped up. and i connect to mobile hotspot