# Strange issue in laptop wifi card , Weak signals

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, drivers, hardware-failure

[Strange issue in Wi-Fi in laptop , Weak signal](https://superuser.com/questions/1627576/strange-issue-in-wi-fi-in-laptop-weak-signal)

this is my previous post in which i experienced a strange issue which i got resolved by swapping the wifi card wires with the WWAN broadband card (antenna) wires . but after few weeks the problem again popped up though not strange as previous(no change in signal strength if tilt laptop screen) but this issue just pops up anytime sometimes i see all my and my neighbours network and sometimes i cant even see mine. is it now a driver issue or some hardware issue as earlier. can it be like the wires get pressed hardly by the laptop hinges(as the wires go from my laptop chasis to back of display) . and for confirmation my computer has the same network card- dell 1506 which shows lot many connections more than my laptop.

pls help.. the hardware technician is asking for 80 dollars+40 dollars (which i can spend in buying a gt1030 hehehe)

thanks a ton !!!

one more thing i just noticed :whenever i uninstall my driver from device manager i see full signal strength and all connections but only for a short duration of time
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3k54.png  before uninstalling

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCUFl.png  after uninstalling

Answer (score 0):

If you've determined it's not an issue due to radio frequency interference (RFI), such as might be caused by a nearby microwave oven or other electrical device, and you've tried different drivers to no avail, you might add an *inexpensive* WiFi USB "dongle", rather than US$120 in repairs.

The [TP-Link WiFi USB Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008IFXQFU), for example, is available for about $US10. [An adapter with an external antenna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08Y88FR4T) may help if the signal is intrinsically weak.

BTW, you do not state how you are measuring signal strength. On Linux, I find free [WaveMon](https://github.com/uoaerg/wavemon), and in Windows, Nirsoft's free [WiFiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) *very* useful tools for monitoring signal strength. You can probably find a [similar tool](https://alternativeto.net/software/wavemon/) for other operating systems. These applications provide much more information that the tools that ship with most PC's.

Comment: one source of interference and/or signal problems on some laptop wifi chipsets is the bluetooth. The OP should disable BT to see if it resolves

Comment: thats all right but when i uninstall the driver from device manager windows automatically reinstalls the new one and for some minutes i see all networks which much better strength .. this is what is bothering me .. and i dont know if these usb dongles works well and i am a power user so i need all usb ports(laptop only have 3)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has a built-in wireless diagnostic command that can print out a lot of data about your wireless connection. It might be a bit too detailed to help with this particular issue, but it could give you a good overall view.

Direct website explaining it:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/analyze-the-wireless-network-report-76da0daa-1db2-6049-d154-7bb679eb03ed

Command to run:
In the search box on the taskbar, type Command prompt, press and hold (or right-click) Command prompt, and then select Run as administrator > Yes.
At the command prompt, type netsh wlan show wlanreport.

If you look closely in the events section of that report, you might see the wireless driver failing or cutting out in some method. This might help pinpoint a cause.

Also: did you reconnect the wifi adapter wires yourself? Maybe one of them could be loose or snagged somewhere in the laptop.

Comment: i pressed both wires of the wifi card in laptop and now i can see much much more networks

Comment: thanks all to help